# How to load data into array of a JS object from DOM using jQuery each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on this code. Why am I not able to push jQuery `each` result into the object array? I have an object like:

```
var app={
        name:null,
        collection:null,
        colors:{},
};
```

and trying to grab DOM data and load them into the object like:

```
 $(".frame-color li span").each(function(index){
        app.colors.push(($(this).text()).substring(4));
  });
```

but I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: app.colors.push is not a function

Comment: Where is app.colors? That error message means that app.colors is not a array. Would you show me your full code?

Comment: Can't push into an object literal. Change it to an array ... `colors:[]`

Comment: That is pretty much all , do u want the DOM part?

Comment: Thanks charlietfl, but can you please let me know how did you know it is object literal I mean on code side?

Comment: I got it. app.colors is not a array. It's just object. You have to change it to array like this. 

`
var app = {
    colors: []
}
`

Comment: very simple... `{}` is object literal and `[]` is array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {

    var app = {

        name:null,
        collection:null,
        colors: [],
    };

    $(".frame-color li span").each(function(index){
        app.colors.push(($(this).text()).substring(4));
    });

    console.log('app : ', app);
    console.log('app.colors : ', app.colors);
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="frame-color">
    <ul>
        <li><span>#f1ddfd</span></li>
        <li><span>#12574f</span></li>
        <li><span>#05464f</span></li>
        <li><span>#ffacee</span></li>
        <li><span>#e3bab3</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```